# CSS makes Anchor tag not function in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, css-float

I am working with a sample website and the header menu html looks like this

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>
        ASP.NET MVC MUSIC STORE</h1>
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li class="first"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Store">Store</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now in Chrome the links work, they change color when hovered and go to the correct page when clicked.  In IE 9 (compatibility mode only) they wouldn't work at all or respond to clicks.

I traced it down to a css style on #header

```
#header
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #5D5A53;
    z-index:999;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

If I take out the float: left; the links work fine.  My question is why would this be the case?

Nothing else on the page changes if I remove this line.

Comment: Try removing the huge `z-index`. If you really need it, try at least lowering it.

Comment: CSS problems. So easy to debug when you have access to the live page, so hard to debug when you only see a fraction of the code.

Comment: Not reproducible with the code posted.